# What's the best way to use Selenium PageObject Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm creating tests using Selenium 2 Web Driver with C#.Net. After reading through a lot of the Selenium documentation, I am left still feeling unsure on how to go about testing using the PageObject design patterns.

Many of the selenium examples are only shown in Java and the API bindings for .Net are not always as similar as one would think they are due to limitations and the standards set by certain languages.

What is the best way to use the PageObject design pattern with PageFactory in .Net Selenium Web Driver?

Eventually, I want my PageObjects to handle more functionality, rather than my NUnit tests using the PageObject IWebElements.

Below is an example of how I am currently going to create my tests moving forward.

```
public class LoginPage
{
    private IWebDriver webDriver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_content_txtPassword")]
    public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_content_cmdSubmit")]
    public IWebElement SubmitButton { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_content_txtUserName")]
    public IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    public LoginPage() { }

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;


        if(!webDriver.Url.Contains("Login.aspx"))
        {
            throw new StaleElementReferenceException("This is not the login page");
        }
        PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, this);
    }

    public HomePage signIn(string username, string password)
    {
        UserName.SendKeys(username);
        Password.SendKeys(password);
        SubmitButton.Submit();

        // Even if i create a NUnit test for this
        // Issue with page loading still occures when I try and return new object
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(webDriver);
        PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, homePage);
        return homePage;
    }
}
```

At the moment this is what I am currently doing with NUnit:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoginPageTest : TestBase
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;
    private HomePage homePage;

    [SetUp]
    [Description("Sets up the test fixture page objects and navigates to the login page.")]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = StartDriver();
        Log.Info("Driver started");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://" + Environment + ");
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, loginPage);
        //driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    }

    [Test]
    [Description("Enters invalid credentials and asserts that a correct error message is displayed.")]
    public void SubmitFormInvalidCredentials()
    {
        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys("invalid");
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys("invalid");
        loginPage.SubmitButton.Click();
        IWebElement invalidCredentials = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_ctl02_title"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Invalid user name or password", invalidCredentials.Text);
    }

    [Test]
    [Description("Enters valid credentials and asserts that the user is taken to the home page.")]
    public void SubmitFormValidCredentials()
    {
        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys("valid");
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys("valid");
        loginPage.SubmitButton.Click();

        homePage = new HomePage();
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, homePage);
        Assert.AreEqual("pattest", homePage.Username.Text);
    }

 }
```

Most of the articles and blog posts I find for selenium webdriver Design Patterns give off contradictions to previous posts I find.

So, what is the right way?

To top this off, I even gave the PageObject design pattern a try.

```
    [Test]
    [Description("Login using PageObject Design Pattern")]
    public void Login()
    {
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        HomePage signIn = loginPage.SignIn("pattest", "pattest");
    }
```

Inside my LoginPage

```
public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;

        if (!driver.Url.Contains("Login.aspx"))
        {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("This is not the login page");
        }
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    public HomePage SignIn(string username, string password)
    {
        UserName.SendKeys(username);
        Password.SendKeys(password);
        SubmitButton.Click();
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }
```

And, of course to show how my HomePage should be initiated with its Constructor:

```
public HomePage(IWebDriver d)
    {
        webDriver = d;
        // I need to use this as its not freaking waiting for my Page to load when I pass the webdriver in the consturctor.
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        try
        {
            wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_loginStatus")));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("This is not the home page.");
        }
        PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, this);
    }
```

How do I use WebDriver PageObject design pattern effectively with testing. 
I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this)`; on the constructor of your base page class:

```
public class Page
{
    public IWebDriver _driver;

    public Page(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this._driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
    }
}
```

Please see the [PageFactory documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

Comment: Yes, this is the structure I ended up with when I started the project. +1

Comment: question, how would you do if the element is `Select` (dropdownlist) in pageobject? i have been told that you can not use pageobject for select(dropdownlist) is that true?

Comment: Can someone answer @Nick Kahn 's question please :)  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the Asserts in the tests and stick with the LoginPage.signIn method, which will throw an exception in case of unsuccessful login. I'm not familiar with NUnit but I guess it supports the 'expected to fail' behavior.

It's better to keep your page-dependent logic in one place(the page class).

I guess you'll have to modify the web UI tests a lot as the main app evolves anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this still doesn't explain how to use the page object design patter or why the way I percieve using it, is causing errors such as the webdriver ignoring the page loads, ( since it should do this automatically ) and why it cuts off loading the page when I hit submit.

It seems to me that its happening when I return a new PageObject, but I'm still passing in a reference to the same web driver, so I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

This whole pageobject design pattern stuff really needs more documentation on the selenium wiki. =/

Comment: I also agree with your advice on the asserts, It does support expected exceptions, one step at a time. Until someone can enlighten me on this particular issue

Comment: I have misunderstood the question, sorry :)

Comment: I fixed the error I was getting, do you think it's acceptable to move assert statements into my actual PageObjects?

And all asserts which expect a thrown exception to be in the Unit Test.

Comment: I would rather make my PageObjects throw exceptions - asserts are test-specific.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up making custom exceptions depending on what problems went wrong and use the Assert.ThrowsException(Exception, () => FunctionThatThrowsException()); 

:)

Comment: Check out this example here : www.paulsodimu.co.uk/Post/Implementing-the-Page-Object-Pattern-in-C-using-Selenium-WebDriver

Comment: @PaulSodimu- Your blog post is great. Folks would benefit from your posting some of its content as an answer and/or encouraging them to download your solution at https://github.com/PaulSodimu/PageObjectPattern.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Browser class to create driver and similar functions such as GoTo() for navigation and Teardown() for closing the browser.`

```
public class Browser
    {
        static IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //static IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        //InternetExplorerOptions  options = new InternetExplorerOptions(); 
        //static IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Program Files\Selenium\");
        public static void GoTo(string url)
        {
            //webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
            webDriver.Url = url;
        }
        public static ISearchContext Driver
        {
            get { return webDriver; }
        }
        public static void Teardown()
        {
            webDriver.Quit();
        }   
        public static void MaximizeWindow()
        {
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }
```

Create individual classes for pages and use PageFactory to initailize the elements.

```
 public class Admin
    {
        public static AdminPage AdminPage
        {
            get
            {
                var adminpage = new AdminPage();
                PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, adminpage);
                return adminpage;
            }

        }
    }
    public class AdminPage
    {
        string Url = "http://172.18.12.225:4444/admin/admin.aspx";
        string Title = "Login";
        string Text = "Admin";
        public void GoTo()
        {
            Browser.GoTo(Url);
        }
        public bool IsAt()
        {
            return Browser.Title == Title;
        }
        public bool Is_At()
        {
            return Browser.Title == Text;
        }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl16_lblUdpSageMesageCustom")]
        public IWebElement UpdateMessage { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "hypPreview")]
        public IWebElement BackHomeLink { get; set; }
        //Login
       // [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_UserName")]
       // public IWebElement UserNameLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_Password")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement PasswordLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_LoginButton")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement LoginLink { get; set; }
        //Forgot Password
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_hypForgotPassword")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement FPWLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_wzdForgotPassword_txtUsername")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement FPWUserNameLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_wzdForgotPassword_CaptchaValue")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement FPWCaptchaLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_wzdForgotPassword_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement FPWNextLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl14_wzdForgotPassword_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_CancelButton")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement FPWCancelLink { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sfToppane")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement TopPane { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sidebar")][CacheLookup]
        public IWebElement sidebar { get; set; }
        //Role
        //[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl19_rptDashBoard_ctl01_hypPageURL")]
        //public IWebElement Role { get; set; }       
        //User
        //[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl19_rptDashBoard_ctl02_hypPageURL")]
        //public IWebElement User { get; set; } 
        public void LogIn(string Username, string Password)
        {
            Browser.MaximizeWindow();
            IWebElement UserNameLink = Browser.WaitForElement(By.Id("ctl14_UserName"), 15);
            UserNameLink.Click();
            UserNameLink.Clear();
            UserNameLink.SendKeys(Username);
            PasswordLink.Click();
            PasswordLink.Clear();
            PasswordLink.SendKeys(Password);
            LoginLink.Click();
        }
}
```

It is a small example with a login functionality.
I hope this might help even though a late reply.

Comment: The above is for the framework and it would be better if you use Microsoft Visual Studio Unit Test Framework for creating tests calling the function of the pages in the unit tests created.

Comment: can you share the code used for Browser.WaitForElement method? Also, how do you get the IWebDriver from an IWebElement created via page object?